# cypher to create linked list inside groups

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have following nodes

```
(Node:{Id=1,Prop1="A",TS=1})
(Node:{Id=2,Prop1="A",TS=25})
(Node:{Id=3,Prop1="A",TS=30})
(Node:{Id=4,Prop1="B",TS=1})
(Node:{Id=5,Prop1="B",TS=5})
(Node:{Id=6,Prop1="B",TS=1000})
 ...
```

I need to group them by Prop1 and link them ordered by TS

```
Id=1->Id=2->Id=3
Id=4->Id=5->Id=6
...
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: MATCH (m1: Node)
MATCH (m2: Node)
WHERE
m1.Prop1 = m2.Prop1
and m1.TS < m2.TS
MERGE (m1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(m2) However it will create links between ts=1 and ts=3

Comment: After playing with it some more I come up with something that might work MATCH (s:Node)
WITH s
ORDER BY s.Prop1, s.TS
WITH COLLECT(s) AS lims
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(lims) - 2) as idx 
WITH lims[idx] AS s1, lims[idx+1] AS s2
where s1.Prop1 == s2.Prop1
MERGE (s1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(s2)

Comment: Great! I suggest you answer your own question and accept it to indicate to the whole community this issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Cypher to do this, with comments explaining each section. This should perform slightly better than the solution you came up with in high volume situations (but use PROFILE to evaluate which is more efficient for your version of Neo4j/schema).

```
// Get all nodes to be linked
MATCH (n:A) 

// Sort them by TS, split by group (id to define equal TS resolution)
WITH n, n.Prop1 as group 
ORDER BY n.TS, id(n) ASC

// Collect nodes and keep them divided by group
WITH COLLECT(n) as list, group

// Split collection into this-next pairs
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(list) - 2) as index
WITH list[index] AS n1, list[index+1] AS n2

// Create relation between each pair
MERGE (n1)-[:NextNode]->(n2)
```

[console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/31uaur)

EDIT:
Here is how to link two seprate groups

```
MATCH (a{Prop1:"A"}) WITH a ORDER BY a.TS ASC WITH COLLECT(a)[-1] as start 
MATCH (b{Prop1:"B"}) WITH start, b ORDER BY b.TS ASC WITH start, COLLECT(b)[0] as end 
MERGE (start)-[:link]->(end)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer! I am stuck again trying to build link between groups where Node with max(Ts) and Prop1=A will get linked to Node with min(Ts) and Prop1=B

Comment: @YevgeniyRozhkov In that case, you want to remove `n.Prop1 as group` and all reference to group; and change the sorting to `ORDER BY n.Prop1, n.TS, id(n) ASC`. If the linking logic isn't based on order, you will want to do that in a separate Cypher. (You can use `WITH n ORDER BY n.prop ASC WITH HEAD(COLLECT(n)) as min, TAIL(COLLECT(n)) as max` to get the min and max nodes of a collection). Or, in your version of the query, just remove the WHERE part.

Comment: I'm sorry, use `COLLECT(n)[1] as min, COLLECT(n)[1] as max` to access first and last element of a collection.

Comment: `COLLECT(n)[0] as min, COLLECT(n)[1] as max`. Sorry out of it today.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your suggestion works perfectly for this case. Do you know if it is possible to select only nodes with maximum timestamp for each group. My case is a little bit more complex than this simple example. Thank you once again!

Comment: @YevgeniyRozhkov `MATCH (n) WITH n ORDER BY n.TS, id(n) ASC WITH COLLECT(n)[-1] as max, n.group as group ...` Will give you the max node from each group. COLLECT groups all elements where all other column values are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I find using the apoc.coll.pairsMin() function to be the cleanest approach to generating the list of nodes to link.

Something like this should work to link within groups (untested, btw):

```
 MATCH (n:Node) 
  WITH n
 ORDER BY n.Prop1, n.TS
  WITH n.Prop1 AS group, apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(n)) AS pairs
UNWIND pairs AS pair
  WITH group, pair[0] AS start, pair[1] AS end
 MERGE (start)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(end)
RETURN group, COUNT(1) AS relationships
```

After reading some comments on other answers, it seems you want to link between groups, as well.

That's a very simple change to the above query, just don't group them to begin with (rely on the global sorting):

```
 MATCH (n:Node) 
  WITH n
 ORDER BY n.Prop1, n.TS
  WITH apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(n)) AS pairs
UNWIND pairs AS pair
  WITH pair[0] AS start, pair[1] AS end
 MERGE (start)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(end)
RETURN COUNT(1) AS relationships
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347952/cypher-to-create-linked-list-inside-groups#comment79657484_46347952):

> *[I have tried]* `MATCH (m1: Node) MATCH (m2: Node) WHERE m1.Prop1 = m2.Prop1 and m1.TS
>   < m2.TS MERGE (m1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(m2)` However it will create links
>   between ts=1 and ts=3

Change your query to:

```
MATCH (m1: Node) MATCH (m2: Node)
WHERE m1.Prop1 = m2.Prop1 and
m1.TS = m2.TS + 1
MERGE (m1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(m2)
```

That is: change the condition `m1.TS < m2.TS` to `m1.TS = m2.TS + 1`.

Comment: TS  can be any number